# TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined faker-js faker

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, requirejs, faker.js

I am trying to use [faker-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker) package, but I unexpectedly get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined` for my variable `businessId` which try to use `faker.datatype.uuid()`

It usually happen when I forget to install `faker-js`, but that's not the case here, and I check that I imported this package. Therefore I am clueless on what I am doing wrong here.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/order
const { initConfig } = require('../../../config');

initConfig();

const sinon = require('sinon');
const faker = require('@faker-js/faker');
const { retryAsyncCall } = require('../../../src/common/helpers/retry-async');
const { createFacebookAdVideoFromUrl } = require('../../../src/common/controllers/facebook/api');

function createPayloadDataBuilder(payload = {}) {
  const template = {
    accountId: faker.datatype.uuid(),
    publicLink: faker.internet.url(),
    videoName: faker.lorem.word(),
    facebookToken: undefined,
    params: null,
    businessId: faker.datatype.uuid(),
  };
  return { ...payload, ...template };
}

describe('Facebook Gateway', () => {
  describe('createFacebookAdVideoFromUrl', () => {
    describe('Given businessId', () => {
      it.only("should create the video calling business's Facebook ids", async () => {
        const businessId = faker.datatype.uuid();
        console.log(faker, businessId);
        const createFacebookAdVideoPayload = createPayloadDataBuilder({
          businessId,
        });

        await createFacebookAdVideoFromUrl(...createFacebookAdVideoPayload);

        // sinon.assert.called(retryAsyncCall);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is a problem to use `crypto.randomUUID()` to generate UUID?

Comment: It's only a symptom, I have the same issue with all the sub-values of `datatype`

Comment: I just try with `faker.internet.url()`, same issue : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it! I need to destructure the import:

`const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');`

Comment: Sadly this does not fix the issue for me

Comment: Fixed for me (using `module.exports = function(){ return { // ... } }`)

Comment: It worked in my case, Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

`faker.random.uuid()` has been moved to `faker.datatype.uuid()`

See the docs: https://fakerjs.dev/api/datatype.html#uuid